# checking validation login showing error using pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Here is  validation form using PDO , Database code which is showing connection to my database  is running correctly.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=filesystem", $username, $password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

and now i am making connection to open a page after validating from database based on correct username and password , Here is code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $user=!empty($_POST['user']) ? trim($_POST['user']) :null ;
    $password=!empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) :null;
    $sql="select * from users where user='$user' and password='$password'";
    if($stmt=$con->query( $sql))
    {
        if($stmt->fetchColumn()>0)
        {
            $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $u_name=$row['user'];
            $u_password=$row['password'];
            if($user==$u_name && $password==$u_password)
            {
                if(isset($_POST['remember']))
                {
                    setcookie('user',$user,time()+60*60*7);
                    setcookie('password',$password,time()+60*60*7);
                }
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                echo "<script> window.location.assign('../index.php'); </script>"; 
                exit();        
            } else {
                echo "nothing";
            }
        } else {
            echo"<script>alert('incorrect user name or password')</script>";
            echo "<script> window.location.assign('login.php'); </script>"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Now  when input credential are right  then why this still is keep going in `else{echo "nothing";}`.Help me please.

Comment: How did you save password? as plain text?

Comment: Pdo with no placeholders? Why not?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile no save with AES_ENCRYPT

Comment: Also you only use the `$row` data once so there is reason to declare new variables.   Just suggesting DRY coding.  Have you printed the values in question to the screen to confirm?

Comment: @Raj According to the Manual AES_ENCRYPT() encrypts a string and returns a binary string. AES_DECRYPT() decrypts the encrypted string and returns the original string. therefore you should use `AES_DECRYPT()` on your select

Comment: Best advice is to use the varchar(255) on the password in your table then hash your password with php `password_hash()` and use `password_verify()` to verify the hash

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i used as per your instruction but still i am receiving same  output .

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i also used the `password_hash()` and verify but still getting same output

Answer (score 0):

As I said above best you change your password column from `AES_ENCRYPT` to varchar(255) then delete the user on your database and start fresh register the user with php `password_hash()` then on login verify the stored hash with `password_verify()`

This is what you will do on register page

```
<?php

$user     = isset($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : null;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

//hash the password
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user,password) VALUES(?,?)")->execute(array($user,$password));

if ($insert) {

    echo "User registered success";
} else {

    //user not registered handle errors
}
?>
```

Then on login

```
<?php

$user     = !empty($_POST['user']) ? trim($_POST['user']) : null;
$password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

$sql = "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE  user = ? LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();

if ($row && password_verify($password, $row['password'])) { //verify pass
    if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        setcookie('user', $user, time() + 60 * 60 * 7);
        setcookie('password', $password, time() + 60 * 60 * 7);
    }

    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    header("location:../index.php");
    exit();
} else {

    echo "incorrect user name or password";
    header("location:login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

**

> NB: When verifying a password store with passwod_hash() do not use any
>   cleansing mechanism

**